# How to change website shortcut icon from default to favicon (google chrome browser)

Tags: google-chrome, browser, icons, shortcut, favicon

We would like to have favicon as an icon for website shortcut. But no matter what we try, we can't do it at all. Is there some trick for doing this? To be precise, google chrome always use default favicon and ignore our setting.

[picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UQVgN.png)

Thank you very much for any advice.

Comment: If you are the owner of the website the  [this page](https://css-tricks.com/favicon-quiz/) might help you.